# Selenium 3 - Selenium Jar issue error is "The jar file Selenium-server-standalon-3.0.0-beta3.jar has no source attachment"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar

Not sure why I am seeing this error.

I installed the new java 8_101. Have the jre and jdk present in the machine

Selenium - Eclipse Luna 64bit.

In my ref library I have:

- Client-combined-3.0.0-beta3-nodeps.jar
- Selenium-server-standalon-3.0.0-beta3.jar (this one has the error)
- junit-4.10(1).jar

this was my script below:

```
/*

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://Selenium driver//geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");  

*/
```

Launches Firefox and Chrome but doesn't go to google.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, try changing this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C://Selenium driver//geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: Sorry to get back after a while been busy with work.. but thanks, Logan,  that didn't work as well. I am starting to think the issue is within my machine.. I got the following error "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms" also got the source not found error.